# Do we need the tag 'concepts'?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Similarly to the question [Do we really need the tag ai-basics?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1578/2444), do we really need the tag [concepts](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concepts)?

The current description of the tag is

> Use for broad questions on the concepts used in AI and implementations. Breakdowns of subfields, methods, and sets of methods, with an emphasis on context and utility.

I think that the description of the tag is unclear and ambiguous, and the tag seems to be superfluous.

First, (too) broad questions are not suited for Stack Exchange websites. Second, we already have the tag [theory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) and [implementation](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/implementation). Regarding the part *Breakdowns of subfields, methods, and sets of methods, with an emphasis on context and utility.*, this is really very vague and unclear. Therefore, I suggest the deletion of this tag from the system.

Answer (score 2):

I agree we don't require the tag 'concepts'. But a quick Google search shows there is some [difference](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_differences_between_conceptual_framework_and_theoretical_framework/amp) between a Conceptual and Theoretical framework. So either the 'concepts' tage need to be redefined, or a new more detailed/self-explanatory tag name needs to be created.

Although, it is debatable whether users will adhere to such narrow difference of definition to sort questions and answers.

Comment: "Although, it is debatable whether users will adhere to such narrow difference of definition to sort questions and answers.", exactly! As I've said in other meta posts, I think we should only create tags for AI topics that are well-known. The word "concept" is very widely applicable and general. It is not specific to AI, and I think that users may not use it consistently. The tag [tag:theory] should be used in all cases where the user needs to ask a general theoretical question (so a question that does not involve any implementation details), unless there are more specific tags.

Comment: For example, if you have a theoretical question related to machine learning, deep learning, neural networks, back-propagation and gradient descent, then you already have 5 tags, so you don't need to use the tag [tag:theory]. However, if your question is related to the definition of AI agents, then you may use the tag [tag:theory] along with the tag [tag:definitions] and [tag:intelligent-agent].